# Getting this statement "Permission Denied" while trying to read or write to firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase

I am trying this code to read data but can't read data:

```
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
        print("---------------")
        print(username)
        print("---------------")
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Please include your datastructure and security rules as text. You can use the [edit] button below your question to edit this information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the default Firebase rules, by default you need be logged to access database. 
If you don't understand, read about firebase rules on [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/?hl=en-us)

you can set

```
{ 
   rule : {
      ".write": true, 
      ".read": true,
   }
}
```

but this rule will leave holes in your application.
the exemple above allow you read and write if you are logged.

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that setting security rules like this creates a massive security hole for an app and its users, and may cause billing issues.  Allowing the world to read and write your database is generally not a good idea.  Also, the rule here will not compile because it's not valid JSON.

Comment: I agree, I only showed how this problem is solved, but the correct way is to make a rule that is adequate for your business.